# Get ImageButton size on onCreate()

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an image button and generate an image dynamicaly at run time with a `Bitmap` object (no problem there):

```
MyButton.setImageBitmap(AMethodReturningBitmap());
```

I want to determine the size of the Bitmap. So, at any time after the `onCreate()` of the activity (like another button click, etc.) I can write:

```
MyButton.setImageBitmap(AMethodReturningSizedBitmatp(MyButton.getWidth(), MyButton.getHeight()));
```

However if I do this at `onCreate()` I get an exception. My "guess" is at that time since the image is not created, it cannot have a width and height. For example I can write:

```
MyButton.setImageBitmap(AMethodReturningSizedBitmatp(16, 16));
```

But I want to it without clicking a button, etc. Is there an event that I can use and be safe that accessing size of the ImageButton does not throw exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `onGlobalLayout()'s` documentation:

> Callback method to be invoked when the global layout state or the
>   visibility of views within the view tree changes

```
myButton.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                        new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        // Ensure you call it only once :       
        myButton.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        // Here you can get the dimensions
        myButton.setImageBitmap(AMethodReturningSizedBitmatp(
                        myButton.getWidth(), myButton.getHeight()));        

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @vikram's suggestion is to wrap the logic in a `Runnable` and post it to the internal message queue of `MyButton`'s parent. That would look like this:

```
MyButtonParent.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        MyButton.setImageBitmap(AMethodReturningSizedBitmatp(MyButton.getWidth(), MyButton.getHeight()));
    }
});
```

This way `setImageBitmap()` does not get called until the other messages in the parent's queue (which include the measurement and layout steps for all its children) have been processed. As a result, by the time your `Runnable` is run, `MyButton` will have a valid width and height.

Comment: This has crossed my mind before: Will this, under no circumstances turn false?  -->  `by the time your Runnable is run, MyButton will have a valid width and height` I guess, cos of this doubt, I always go for `postDelayed`.

Comment: @vikram: Actually, the proper approach would be to post it to parent's message queue (I'll update that in my answer). [According to the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html#delegate), a regular post ensures the parent's children will have been laid out by the time the `Runnable` is run. A delayed post makes little sense, as you can't guarantee the logic is run at an appropriate point in time. I've always used the 'post' approach without problems.

Comment: parent.post(...) makes sense. Thanks.